# how to input the date in python?

Tags: python, date

Here is my program:

```
import datetime

b=input()
a = datetime.date(b)-datetime.datetime.now().date()

print(a)
```

When I enter the date `2015,2,2`, or some another, I have a problem

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 4, in <module>
    a = datetime.date(b)-datetime.datetime.now().date()
TypeError: an integer is required
```

How to input the date right? I tried `2015-2-2` and `2015.2.2` and `2015-2-2` and other versions. But nothing works :(

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime

Comment: You need to explicitly parse the string into a date; the `datetime()` class does not parse strings for you. There is a `datetime.strptime()` method that you can tell what pattern to look for.

Comment: and how to use this method?

Comment: b=datetime.strptime(input(), "%Y-%m-%d")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'strptime'

Comment: Yes! I done it! Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

`datetime.date` requires 3 int arguments and you are passing a touple

Extract the ints from the tuple using an index to grab each position

```
import datetime

b=input()

a = datetime.date(b[0],b[1],b[2])-datetime.datetime.now().date()

print(a)
```

Example

```
b = input()

2015,4,4

a = datetime.date(b[0],b[1],b[2]) - datetime.datetime.now().date() 

print(a)
```

503 days, 0:00:00

Comment: I'm sorry, but something is wrong...:(  2015,4,4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 5, in <module>
    a = datetime.date(b[0],b[1],b[2])-datetime.datetime.now().date()
TypeError: an integer is required